# getting javascript 'Sys' is undefined error

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, scriptmanager, plesk

On the developement machine my website is working fine but I am getting javascript **'Sys' is undefined** error on hosting server and my AJAX is not working.

I have make a sample page and scriptmanager on it, Please look into this.
http://nexapps.com/default2.aspx

button and textbox is in AJAX updatepanel, but when hit to button page is full postback.

Note: hosting server--IIS7, but my other websites are working fine on the same server

Thanks

Comment: Your other websites running on this server also use ASP.NET AJAX extensions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like your web.config, see if any of this [info](https://web.archive.org/web/20200812072043/http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2007/07/15/113963.aspx) helps out.

Comment: After google search, I have found this URL very first, but implement the thing that have mention in this, but could not help out. after that I have posted the issue on forum. Thanks