# Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Sys' is undefined

Tags: asp.net, ajax, undefined, sys

I am having problems with an intermitent error in an ASP.Net Ajax enabled website. The error I am receiving is the old faithful "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Sys' is undefined" error. Googling this error usually turns up the suggestion to add the correct "httpHandlers" and "httpModules" into the "web.Config" file. The web.config file for this project already has the following lines for those two sections. See below:

```
<system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
        <remove path="*.asmx" verb="*"/>
        <add path="*.asmx" verb="*" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
        <add path="*_AppService.axd" verb="*" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
        <add path="ScriptResource.axd" verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
        <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" validate="false"/>
        <add path="Telerik.ReportViewer.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms.HttpHandler, Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=3.0.9.430, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be" validate="true"/>
        <add type="Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms.HttpHandler, Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=3.0.9.430, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be" path="Telerik.ReportViewer.axd" verb="*" validate="true"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
        <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

The error is intemittent, it sometimes does not present at all when debugging a page, and other times it will present constitently for anything up to a day or so?
Please can anyone else suggest another area which may require attention.

BTW, we are using Telerik ajax controls on the page. One of our custom JavaScripts does render before the scriptmanager.  ahve tried using both "RadScriptManager1.RegisterClientScriptBlock(...)" and "ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(...)" but both seem to render the script block above the "Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize(...)" line.

Any help apprecuiated. Thanks in advance,
Best regards,
Duane.

Comment: Have a look at this thread check my question and provided answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437799/getting-javascript-sys-is-undefined-error

Comment: Thanks Muhammad, I'll check it out.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?  If I manually include references to MicrosoftAjax.js and MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js in my RadScriptManager, it works around the problem... but I'd rather not hack it.

Comment: @Josh - Sadly no, we never got round this. I have changed jobs recently and we use **ASP.Net MVC 2.0**, here and I haven't had a repeat of it under that environment (yet!).

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize(...)
```

do

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize(...)
});
```

(yes, jquery)

Comment: Hi y34h,

I'm not sure if I can change the code as it appears to be auto generated..?